# Meteor - MongoDB Error: Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am following the recently published book "[Getting Started with Meteor.js JavaScript Framework](http://amzn.com/1782160825)" by Isaac Strack.  The book works with Meteor 0.5.0.  I am working with version 0.5.4.

In the book you build an app with a few categories to which you insert data for tracking household items, and who they may be lent to. I deployed the app to a [meteor subdomain](http://lendlib.meteor.com/), and it is working perfectly. It does not replicate my local MongoDB error.

[image: LendLib]

I am in Chapter 5, and I have just removed autopublish from the app, and specified my local channels for data.

Locally, under the under the "Tools" category only, when I try to add a new item to the category, I recieve this error in my browser console:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '/Lists/update' Error {} Error: Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at LocalCollection._modifiers.$addToSet (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/modify.js?e7f02f0df0bff9f0b97236f9548637b7ede1ac74:178:13)
    at Function.LocalCollection._modify (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/modify.js?e7f02f0df0bff9f0b97236f9548637b7ede1ac74:53:9)
    at LocalCollection._modifyAndNotify (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?7f5131f0f3d86c8269a6e6db0e2467e28eff6422:474:19)
    at LocalCollection.update (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?7f5131f0f3d86c8269a6e6db0e2467e28eff6422:444:12)
    at m.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js?3ef9efcb8726ddf54f58384b2d8f226aaec8fd53:415:36)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata/livedata_connection.js?367884963b120d457819216ff713b2586b266dde:540:25
    at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor/dynamics_browser.js?46b8d1f1158040fcc2beb7906ec2f932871a398d:21:19)
    at _.extend.apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata/livedata_connection.js?367884963b120d457819216ff713b2586b266dde:539:47)
    at Meteor.Collection.(anonymous function) [as update] (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js?3ef9efcb8726ddf54f58384b2d8f226aaec8fd53:266:23) logging.js:30
update failed: Internal server error logging.js:30
```

The tools category already has one item in it which was submitted earlier in the tutorial.  If I type into the console `lists.findOne({Category:"Tools"});` I get the output which recognizes an item in the Object:

```
Object
  Category: "Tools"
  _id: "eaa681e1-83f2-49f2-a42b-c6d84e526270"
    items: Object
      LentTo: "Steve"
      Name: "Linear Compression Wrench"
      Owner: "me"
      __proto__: Object
  __proto__: Object
```

However, the screen output is blank:

[image]

Naturally I have tried restarting the meteor server & shut down the browser, but no resolution.  I am new to MongoDB, so I am unclear as to where to turn to understand what is causing this problem, or why.

You can [view the app here](http://lendlib.meteor.com/). You can view the code on my [GitHub](https://github.com/stat30fbliss/LendLib).

Comment: is it only tools that does this? Could you try running `meteor reset` (please backup all your stuff itll clear the database) and see if it still happens? I feel its the database because when you deploy to meteor.com it uses a fresh db

Comment: @Akshat That did the trick, thank you! And yes, it was only 'Tools' that was not cooperating.

Comment: You probably added it before in the tutorials manually but the items bit with the wrong kind of array (associative I suspect, using curly brackets {} instead of straight ones [])

Comment: @Akshat I think you are exactly right.  If you converted this to an answer I would gladly accept.

Comment: Hey I faced the same problem and yes "meteor reset" does seem to resolve this error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function addItem(list_id, item_name) {
    if(!item_name && !list_id)
      return;
    lists.update({_id:list_id}, {$addToSet:{items:{Name:item_name}}});
  }
```

Seems like you're trying to add an object to a set. You're getting an error on simulation. Let's investigate that error. The code that errors out:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/minimongo/modify.js

```
 $addToSet: function (target, field, arg) {
    var x = target[field];
    if (x === undefined)
      target[field] = [arg];
    else if (!(x instanceof Array))
      throw Error("Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array");
    else { ...
```

Uh oh, `throw Error("Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array.")`.

Look at your code:

```
Object
  Category: "Tools"
  _id: "eaa681e1-83f2-49f2-a42b-c6d84e526270"
...
  items: Object
...
```

`items` is an object, not an array! It will error out.

Can you `$addToSet` to an object with Mongo? Let's look at the code.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/4a4f9b1d6dc79d1ba4a7d7eaa9e4eb6d00aa466c/db/update.cpp

```
 case ADDTOSET: {
            uassert( 12592 ,  "$addToSet can only be applied to an array" , in.type() == Array );
            ...
        }
```

Nope! This is from old Mongo code, because the contemporary codebase is sprawling, but same thing.

I only found one `insert` in your code.

```
'keyup #add-category': function(e, t) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    var catVal = String(e.target.value || "");
    if (catVal) {
      lists.insert({Category:catVal});
      Session.set('adding_category', false);
    }
  }
},
```

Try `lists.insert({Category:catVal,items:[]})`. So that items is initialized as an array rather than an object when it was first used.

Also, I don't think `$addToSet` compares objects in an array the way you would like anyway, so consider making a separate collection `Items` that contains a `categoryId`.

It is purely a coincidence that it is working on one place and not another.

Comment: Excellent response!  Drilling into this issue, I believe you have just brought about a problem in the tutorial I am following.  The book has never specified the necessity for using an Array instead of an Object in this type of submission.  I was able to resolve the issue currently with the comment to my answer by running `meteor reset`, but it seems you have opened a much larger issue with the book in question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem following the same guide. When using the inserts directly from the guide (the Tools and DVDs) minimongo inserts the items as objects instead of arrays. I don't know if it was simply a mistake or if the code base has changed, either way I changed:

```
lists.insert({Category:"DVDs", items: {Name:"Mission Impossible", Owner:"me", LentTo:"Alice"}});
```

to

```
lists.insert({Category:"DVDs", items: [{Name:"Mission Impossible", Owner:"me",LentTo:"Alice"}]});
```

just encasing the items in [] to force it to an array and did likewise with the insert for tools. Works great now.